# Regression kNN model vs. Classification kNN model

Tags: regression, classification, modeling, k-nearest-neighbour

I was wondering what is the difference between regression kNN model and classification kNN model. I tried Googling and no success. In presentation from lectures we only have graphs of errors of mentioned models and no description as to what these models are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out that the difference is:

- **regression** model: codomain of model is a **continuous** space, e.g. $\mathbb{R}$
- **classification** model: codomain of model is a **discrete** space, e.g. $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 4):

The key differences are:

- *KNN regression* tries to predict the **value** of the output variable
  by using a local average.
- *KNN classification* attempts to predict the **class** to which the output variable belong by computing the local probability.

Answer (score 0):

Knn Classifier: Predicts a **class** by using the **highest majority** category among its k nearest neighbors.

Knn Regression: Predicts a **value** by using the **mean** of the k nearest neighbors.